# Sikuli code to Scroll to end of the page in a silverlight application

Tags: jenkins, silverlight, sikuli

I am working on automating a silverlight application and executing it from jenkins.

**Problem:**

I am trying to access the folder "SandboxRefresh" present at the bottom of the page in the silverlight application that I am working on.

**Code below:**

```
SilverlightElement jobfolder2 = extab
      .GetFirstOrDefaultUIElement(criteria.ByName("SandboxRefresh")
      .AndByClassName("TextBlock"));
```

**Issue Observed:**

Executing the above java code in Eclipse resulted in Arithmetic overflow exception as it could not find the element at the bottom of the page.

**Please note:**

I tried many approaches that worked for me in my machine but it did not work on Jenkins.
ex:

```
Button  bt= new Button();
Screen scr= new Screen();
scr.wheel(bt.WHEEL_DOWN, 2);
```

The above code worked well to scroll to the bottom of the page but it is not always successful. Sometimes the code gets executed but scroll does not happen.

Can anyone help me with an approach to scroll to the desired element in silverlight application when launched the code from jenkins?

Comment: I have observed that scr.wheel(bt.WHEEL_DOWN, 4); is working but not always. I tried several times by changing the count of wheel_down and worked few times but not always. Sometimes the code gets executed but the scroll does not happen.  Has anyone faced similar issue? Please help me with this I am new to Silverlight app

Answer (score 0):

Two quick things, are you waiting for previous code to finish and is the window still in focus?